# Python : Adding to txt file

Tags: python

Here is my code (Sorry for using another language) :

```
def answer_L():
    while True:
        question = input("\tFikseerige sade kujul [Identifikaator] [20] (C): ")
        if question == "C": #Läheb algusesse tagasi
            main()
        try:
            nimi = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z]+)\]", question)
            number = re.search(r"\[([0-9]+)\]", question)
            number = number.group(0)
            nimi = nimi.group(0)
        except Exception:
            continue
        if ((nimi[0] and nimi[-1] and number[0] and number[-1]) != ("[" or "]")):
            sademed = nimi + number
            to_txt = str(sademed)
        with open('andmebaas.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
            file.write(" - " + to_txt + "\n")
            print("\tSade fikseeritud!")
            print("")
            main()
```

It used to work, added input to txt, but now it suddenly decided not to add anything to the txt file. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: What error do you receive? What happens instead of getting the expected result?

Comment: is it still printing the date and the `-` characters? because it looks like you have a really wack `if` statement that would throw all kinds of weird stuff at you

Comment: It creates new txt file if I delete the old one, but it adds nothing to the new or already existing file. It gives no errors whatsoever

Comment: I think your main problem is you are calling `main` inside of your `with` block which means that `flush` and `close` may not be getting called implicitly before `main`. I would explicitly call `file.flush()` after your `file.write` calls (remember that writing to file is buffered)

Comment: Thank you R Nar, that fixed it :)